# issue for condition on unique raws in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I want to print  rows of a table in a file, the issue is when I use a `readline` the reprint me the result several times, here is my input file

```
aa      ,DEC    ,file1.txt
aa      ,CHAR   ,file1.txt    
cc      ,CHAR   ,file1.txt  
dd      ,DEC    ,file2.txt
bb      ,DEC    ,file3.txt
bb      ,CHAR   ,file3.txt 
cc      ,DEC    ,file1.txt
```

Here is the result I want to have:

printed in file1.txt

```
aa#DEC,CHAR
cc#CHAR,DEC
```

printed in file2.txt

```
dd#DEC
```

printed in file3.txt

```
bb#DEC,CHAR
```

here is it my attempt :

```
(cat input.txt|while read line
do
table=`echo $line|cut -d"," -f1
variable=`echo $line|cut -d"," -f2
file=`echo $line|cut -d"," -f3

echo ${table}#${variable}, 

done ) > ${file}
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: @0stone0 done ; thank you

Comment: You need to redirect echo to the relevant file within the loop. At the moment, all of the output is going to one file.

Comment: Please copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net (as instructed in the bash tag info, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info), fix the issues it tells you about, read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and then re-post if you still have a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following, written and tested in shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  sub(/^,/,"",$3)
}
FNR==NR{
  sub(/^,/,"",$2)
  arr[$1,$3]=(arr[$1,$3]?arr[$1,$3]",":"")$2
  next
}
(($1,$3) in arr){
  close(outputFile)
  outputFile=$3
  print $1"#"arr[$1,$3] >> (outputFile)
  delete arr[$1,$3]
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  sub(/^,/,"",$3)             ##Substituting starting comma in 3rd field with NULL.
}
FNR==NR{                      ##Checking condition FNR==NR will be true when first time Input_file is being read.
  sub(/^,/,"",$2)             ##Substituting starting comma with NULL in 2nd field.
  arr[$1,$3]=(arr[$1,$3]?arr[$1,$3]",":"")$2 
##Creating arr with index of 1st and 3rd fields, which has 2nd field as value.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(($1,$3) in arr){             ##Checking condition if 1st and 3rd fields are in arr then do following.
  close(outputFile)           ##Closing output file, to avoid "too many opened files" error.
  outputFile=$3               ##Setting outputFile with value of 3rd field.
  print $1"#"arr[$1,$3] >> (outputFile)
##printing 1st field # arr value and output it to outputFile here.
  delete arr[$1,$3]           ##Deleting array element with index of 1st and 3rd field here.
}
' Input_file Input_file       ##Mentioning Input_file 2 times here.
```

Comment: it's really working but can you give more explanation about Line 7 in your code ? what means the "?" and  ,",":"")$2 in tihs line and  also line 14 please,thank you

Comment: @BADS, your welcome, happy that it helped you. it uses ternary operators. its syntax is like: `condition_check?value(when condition is TRUE):value(when condition is false)` format. `arr[$1,$3]` means to check if its NOT NULL then append current line's 2nd field value to its existing value(as per requirement) OR add it newly to array as array will be empty. I hope its clear now, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single pass `gnu awk` like this:

```sh
awk -F ' *, *' '{
   map[$3][$1] = (map[$3][$1] == "" ? "" : map[$3][$1] ",") $2
}
END {
   for (f in map)
      for (d in map[f])
         print d "#" map[f][d] > f
}' file
```

This will populate this data:

`=== file1.txt ===`

```
aa#DEC,CHAR
cc#CHAR,DEC
```

`=== file2.txt ===`

```
dd#DEC
```

`=== file3.txt ===`

```
bb#DEC,CHAR
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code. You can use the built-in `read` to split on a comma, and the parentheses are completely unnecessary.

```sh
while IFS=, read -r table variable file
do
    echo "${table}#${variable}," >>"$file"
done< input.txt
```

Using `$file` in a redirect after `done` is an error; the shell wants to open the file handle to redirect to before `file` is defined.  But as per your requirements, each line should go to a different `file.

Notice also [quoting fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and the omission of the [useless `cat`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Wrapping fields with the same value onto the same line would be comfortably easy with an Awk postprocessor, but then you might as well do all of this in Awk, as in the other answer you already received.